# Cannot communicate with ESXi through CIM (port 5989)

Tags: vmware, esxi

We have recently started experiencing problems with communication with our ESXi devices through CIM, TCP port 5989. At first we thought this was related to our remote monitoring and maintenance tool, N-central by SolarWinds N-able, however we now have reason to believe that this is not the case.

The reason for why I believe this is a Vmware is that I've attempted to reach one of the ESXi devices at 5989 by browsing to it with Internet Explorer. These attempts have all resulted in the HTTP error message 501/505 Not Implemented.

I have already attempted to browse to the page with HTTP 1.1 both enabled and disabled in Internet Explorer, no change. I've tried with and without compatibility view, no change. I've tried Google Chrome, I only get a blank page and when I check the response from the server Google Chrome just says "Failed to load response data."

Is anyone able to assist me in figuring out what is wrong, and fixing the error(s)? Please do let me know what information is required to best troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstood of your question;

the port 5989 descripted here in vmware website:
https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2039095

vcenter server should access the esxi host with this port(CIM XML transactions over HTTPS), the error code 501/505 means that the esxi host did not recognize your client(which you use browser try connected to).

if you can pretend the agent to be vcenter, I guess you can fix the problem.